# Keeping aspect ration when resizing images using WideImage PHP library

Tags: php, image, wideimage

I am looking to resize an image to a pre-defined maximum size keeping the aspect ratio with the help of WideImage Library.

**Example:**

Maximum Allowed Dimesions: 200x200

Input Image Dimension: 300x200 logo (1,5:1 aspect ratio),

Current Output Image Dimension: 200x200

Expected Output Image Dimension : 200x133 (1,5:1 aspect ratio).

Currently the images are distorted as aspect ratio is changed. What should be done to keep that aspect ratio?

I am using the code found below.

```
$targetWidth = 200;
$targetHeight = 200;

$sourceRatio = $sourceWidth / $sourceHeight;
$targetRatio = $targetWidth / $targetHeight;

if ( $sourceRatio < $targetRatio ) {
    $scale = $sourceWidth / $targetWidth;
} else {
    $scale = $sourceHeight / $targetHeight;
}

$resizeWidth = (int)($sourceWidth / $scale);
$resizeHeight = (int)($sourceHeight / $scale);


$img->resize($resizeWidth, $resizeHeight)
```

PS: I got the above logic from [Resize image without distortion keeping aspect ratio then crop excess using WideImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355954/resize-image-without-distortion-keeping-aspect-ratio-then-crop-excess-using-wide)

Comment: Why is this down-voted? plz do explain if anything is not clear. I am not an expert.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. From the doc: "By default, resizing keeps the original image’s aspect ratio and the resulting image fits the given dimensions from the inside." So $img->resize(200,200) should be enough.

Comment: No. It won't as you say.

Comment: I'm just using `WideImage::load($img)->resizeDown(1024,768)->saveToFile($filename)` and all my images (that can have different aspect ratio, be in portrait or landscape) still keep their aspect ratio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simple logic came to my help.

```
$targetWidth = 200;
$targetHeight = 200;

$ratio = $srcWidth / $srcHeight;

if ($ratio > 1) {
    $resizeWidth = $targetWidth;
    $resizeHeight= $targetHeight / $ratio;
} else {
    $resizeWidth = $targetWidth * $ratio;
    $resizeHeight= $targetHeight;
}

$img->resize($resizeWidth, $resizeHeight)
```