# PHP Image resizing before uploading in the specified Directory

Tags: php, html, css, image

Hi I'm developing a site wherein a user can upload his/her profile picture. My upload page has an img tag so that a user can preview what their image would look like before they upload it after they have selected this picture the thing is the image's name would be fetched from the database later on. here is my the snippet for it

```
 <img id="imgs" src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="your image"/>
```

my uploader goes something like this

```
if ( !!$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] ) // is the file uploaded yet?
{
    $info = explode('.', strtolower( $_FILES['file']['name']) ); // whats the extension of the file
    $temp = explode(".",$_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    $filename = rand(1,9999) . '.' .end($temp);
    if ( in_array( end($info), $allow) ) // is this file allowed
    {
        if ( move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $todir .  $filename ) )
        {

        }
    }
    else
    { }
}
```

by the way this uploader script is from a tutorial so yeah you might find several security and other issues here..

What I'm having trouble is the image looks fine when I uploaded an image with a dimension of 200x200 because in my css I have defined `imgs` with a width and height set both at 200px but if I uploaded other images that doesnt meet the the width and height that I have set on my css the image turns into stretched if its bigger

Any ideas out there how can I fix this?
I also tried defining sizes on the img directly and turned out the same obviously
can I fix this with just css alone?

Comment: Are you looking for a CSS fix to the img tag? If so, #imgs { width:200px, height:200px; } or <img ... style="width:200px; height:200px">

Comment: yes if that is possible..

Comment: You could use a div, instead of img, with a background image with no-repeat and contain or cover for background size. It's a little inefficient because the user may upload a super large file so it makes for slower loading.

Comment: as much as possible I want to avoid on-site cropping which is why I didnt consider using jquery *fyi* guys.. but if there really is no other way I might go for that though..  :(

Comment: This is just pure css my friend. Other options are server side cropping, but that involves more work. Please advise.

Comment: @Rasclatt I also want to avoid that are there fallbacks for that?

Comment: The only downside is the fact that someone could upload a big file, but if you don't care about that using contain or cover will keep proportions but fit inside a 200px x 200px without stretching.

Comment: Hmm I think I'll give it a test on both your advice guys.. I'll keep you updated thanks for the feedback :)

Comment: You could implement a PHP script that resizes their image, previews it exactly as it would go in the database, and if they accept, it could save to the DB. Are you looking for a solution along these lines?

Comment: Yes I'm looking for a solution similar to that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple tutorial about image resizing at https://phpmatters.com/resize-image-using-php/

Here is a sample snippet of how you could resize your user images. There are several intelligent options. PHP resizing is smarter than allowing users to insert huge images in the HTML page (the CSS-only sizing method).

For example, if you want to resize to a specifed width (e.g. 200px) but keep the dimensions ratio the same then the script can work out the required height for you, just use the resizeToWidth function.

```
<?php
    include('SimpleImage.php');
    $image = new SimpleImage();
    $image->load('picture.jpg');
    $image->resizeToWidth(200);
    $image->save('picture200x200.jpg');
?>
```

On the PHP size, you can also reject images smaller than 200x200 so you don't have to worry about unacceptably small images being saved.

> ...this plugin is no longer supported due to security exploits

FWIW, if you have access to the .htaccess file on your server, adding this will deny external access to your timthumb.php. It's such a great library if used internally.

```
# Prevent 'timthumb' hack attempt
RewriteRule ^(.*)?(timthumb\.php)$ - [F]
```

**EDIT:** An alternative library to TimThumb is the WideImage library that has many features at http://wideimage.sourceforge.net/examples/resizing/

Here is a thread on SO about using it here: [Keeping aspect ration when resizing images using WideImage PHP library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19469556/keeping-aspect-ration-when-resizing-images-using-wideimage-php-library)

Comment: The tutorial and the actual snippet is pretty simple to understand but it says there that this plugin is no longer supported due to security exploits. but I guess I could try to look for a plugin similar to this line

Comment: There was a wordpress hack involving TimThumb, but it was do to how it was implemented. In simple cases like the above code it is not usually a problem. However, there is an alternative: http://wideimage.sourceforge.net/examples/resizing/ and a demo http://wideimage.sourceforge.net/wp-content/current/demo/?demo=resize

Comment: I see thanks I'll try out then thanks will update you as soon as I can :)

Comment: TimThumb is excellent and easy to use internally. I updated my answer to reflect a tweak you can do to prevent external access to that script. I still use it as it's so convenient.

Comment: sorry went on a holiday so yeah I wasnt able to get back to you yes so far its working just trying to find out if there are any side issues I have used the timthumbs btw.. :D

Answer (score 2):

If you want to rely only on CSS for resizing don't use `width` and `height` but `max-width` and `max-height`. Example (untested):

```
.my-img {
    max-width: 200px;
    max-height: 200px;   
}
```

This way you should be able to preserve the width/height ratio.

Comment: what happens if the image is smaller than the img/div? will it follow the img/div tag or will the image remain small but the img/div tag will follow that image and will distort my current design?

Comment: It will remain small. The good news is you can use width or height, but just one of them. The other should be a max-*. That way you can enforce a width OR height and have the other be adjusted automatically for you.

Comment: hmm I'm not sure I understand sorry do you mean it like this? `#imgs{ max-width :200px; height:100% };`

Comment: I see Ok I'll try this one :)

Answer (score 2):

I would add to what tacone has commented.You should do it like this.

```
img#imgs {
        height: 100%;
        max-height: 200px;             
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 200px;

}
```

Comment: @kim If the image is smaller than the div/img then the div will shrink to that image size.

Comment: so should I add an outer div for the img tag? just so that the 200x200 dimension could be preserved?

Comment: @KimOliveros if you want to preserve the 200x200 space in all cases then it should be something like this.      <code> .container {
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
        }
        .container img {
            max-width: 200px;
            max-height: 200px;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
</code>

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple alternates to other answers.

One option is to physically modify the image. Here is a working GDLib image resize/crop that will resize the image as well as crop:

[Crop/Resize Image Function using GD Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28002244/crop-resize-image-function-using-gd-library/28008400#28008400)

Another option is to do a `<div>` you can use a combination of header `css` and inline `css`:

```
<style>
div#img {
    /* don't repeat background */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    /* "cover" will force the image to flood the background */
    /* based on smaller dimension */
    background-size: cover;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
}
</style>

<div id="img" style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/200x200.jpg');"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should keep the height you want and proper aspect ratio.Any sized image will not grow past the predefined 200 X 400 set in the CSS.

```
CSS:
body{margin: 0;padding:0;}
#styled>div{
    position:relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width:400px;
    background: #333;
    text-align:center;
    border:1px solid lime;
    }
#styled>div>img{
    max-height:200px;
    }
#not-styled>div{
    position:relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #333;
    text-align:center;
    border:1px solid blue;
    }



 HTML:
<div id="styled">
        <div><img src="path/to/your/image.png" alt="" /><p>img size: 250x250</p></div>
        <div><img src="path/to/your/image2.png" alt="" /><p>img size: 850x500</p></div>
    </div>
    <div id="not-styled">
        <p>NOT styled</p>
        <div><img src="path/to/your/image.png" alt="" /><p>img size: 250x250</p></div>
        <div><img src="path/to/your/image2.png" alt="" /><p>img size: 850x500</p></div>
    </div>
```

You can see an example at [webbdesign.ca/photo_aspect_example.html](http://webbdesign.ca/photo_aspect_example.html)